# Android Custom shape for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

I am trying to create a custom design for EditText. See the attached image below,

[image]

I am trying to achieve this using a custom shape like the one defined below.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/places_ic_search"
        android:width="30dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"></shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="30dp"
        android:drawable="@color/white">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient android:startColor="#000000" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:angle="90"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But the search icon is not displayed. How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

I have applied the answer by tiny sunlight and the EditBox looks like this, Search icon is no aligned to the left.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this :

1. For the border part, you could do it with a drawable like you did
2. For the search icon, instead of trying to put it in the drawable file, why not set it in you `EditText` xml layout, using `android:drawableLeft`, you can then set padding using `android:paddingLeft` and `android:drawablePadding`

Answer (score 1):

I edit my answer. Edit `Shape.xml` as below:

[image]

Shape.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#FF0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="3dp"
        android:right="3dp"
        android:top="3dp"
        android:bottom="3dp"
        >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF0000" />\
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="left" android:left="10dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" android:gravity="left">

        </bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I edit this answer one more time. This code will display like your sample.

Comment: Use bitmap and android:gravity="left".

Comment: I recommend you to use android:drawableLeft.Because you can't limit size of drawable in xml.And you needn't to set a paddingLeft if you  use android:drawableLeft.

Comment: Thank you for helpful tip :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFF" android:angle="90"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"></corners>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/places_ic_search"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
          android:height="10dp"
          android:width="30dp">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Can you please check the edited answer, I have added the screenshot after applying your answer. The icon is not aligned properly.